# Getting .NET Core, WS Federation, Identity Core Issue with TicketDataFormat

Tags: cookies, .net-core, ws-federation, asp.net-core-identity

I have two applications that are using WS Federation and I am working to migrate one of these applications over to .NET Core. These two applications need to be able to share cookies and this is where I am running into an issue on the .NET Core side.

This is a portion of my Startup.cs

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Context>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
    //LOGIN WORKS CORRECTLY WITH THE BELOW LINE COMMENTED
    options.TicketDataFormat = new AuthTicketDataFormat();
    options.Cookie.Name = "cookiename";
    options.Cookie.Path = "/";
    options.Cookie.Domain = "";
});

services.ConfigureExternalCookie(options => {
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
    //LOGIN WORKS CORRECTLY WITH THE BELOW LINE COMMENTED
    options.TicketDataFormat = new AuthTicketDataFormat();
    options.Cookie.Name = "cookiename";
    options.Cookie.Path = "/";
    options.Cookie.Domain = "";
});

services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddWsFederation(options => {
        // MetadataAddress represents the Active Directory instance used to authenticate users.
        options.MetadataAddress = authentication.GetValue<string>("AdfsWsFedMetadataUri");
        // Wtrealm is the app's identifier in the Active Directory instance.
        // For ADFS, use the relying party's identifier, its WS-Federation Passive protocol URL:
        options.Wtrealm = authentication.GetValue<string>("AdfsRelyingPartyIdentifier");
    });
```

I am able to see that I do receive a cookie in the Network tab, but the issue I am having is that I am being put into an infinite loop because on my anonymous Callback endpoint I have the following:

```
var loginInfo = await this._signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
//loginInfo is always coming back as null
if (loginInfo == null) {
    return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
```

It seems the issue is being caused by options.TicketDataFormat and creating a custom format for the cookie. The cookie seems to be created correctly with the ticketDataFormat, but getExternalLoginInfoAsync on signInManager is always returning null.

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated as I've been banging my head against the wall for a day trying to figure this out.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm looking for the same.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Luckily we were able to get our requirements changed and are no longer using WS Fed.